# Java: deleting gz files failed occasionally

Tags: java, io

## UPDATE 2: Please close this question

After further debugging it is found that the problem is not in the inner try block, but a bug inside the 'while' loop. An exception was caused there and was not caught, which therefore skips the inner try block. Apologies for my mistake, please delete this thread.

## UPDATE: added logging to capture errors during delete.

I am downloading 8000ish GZ files from a server, process its content locally, then delete the downloaded copy upon completion. I am running this over a number of threads, each process a disjoint batch of GZ files. But I do not understand for what reason that my code does not successfully delete the GZ files occasionally (not always). The code generally looks like this:

```
....
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(....class.getName());

.....


for (String inputGZFile : gzFiles) { //gzFiles is a list of urls to be process by this thread
    try {
        File downloadTo = new 
        File(this.outFolder + "/" + new File(downloadFrom.getPath()).getName());
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(downloadFrom, downloadTo);

        InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(downloadTo);
        InputStream gzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileStream);
        Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(gzipStream, Charset.forName("utf8"));
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(decoder);
        inputScanner.useDelimiter(" .");

        while (inputScanner.hasNextLine() && (content = inputScanner.nextLine()) != null) {
                //do something
        }

        try {
                inputScanner.close();
                FileUtils.forceDelete(downloadTo);
            }catch (Exception e){
                LOG.info("\t thread " + id + " deleting gz file error "+ inputGZFile);
                LOG.info("\t thread " + id+ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The only reason I can think of is that the scanner did not close the file or release the file handle. But that would be strange because I already call the close method to close the scanner.

Any suggestions highly appreiciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause of the problem is discovered and that has nothing to do with the problem described here.

Answer (score 1):

Without the ability to look into your log files, or debug your system first hand, it is close to impossible to tell you what is going wrong here.

But what you can definitely do: do that call to `FileUtils.forceDelete(downloadTo);` within a finally block for example.

The whole point of try/catch/finally is to enable you to **enforce** that specific actions always take place, no matter what happened in the try block!

Also note: if you are unable to tell what your code does, then add **logging** support to it. So that instead of `printStackTrace();` you log the whole exception to a place where it does *not* get lost.

Meaning: the real answer here is that you step back and take the necessary actions to find out where your problems are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a try catch block for the forcedelete statement and re-run my program. However, still lots of gz files are not deleted. But when I look for exceptions in the log file by 'cat log.log | grep 'deleting gz file error', there are nothing. I am really baffled. What else can I do?

Comment: @Ziqi Well, I would add *more* info logs then. And I would carefully look into that one method `forceDelete()`. It could well be a bug in there. But as said, we are back to my initial comment: from my perspective, I can only give vague hints. One needs to sit in front of your system to reasonably debug this.